# How do I output all BASH results of find to a single variable? More details in post

Tags: linux, bash, variables, find, printf

**LATEST UPDATE:**

I nearly have it figured out with some help from Richard Jessop and his comment. This is the output I currently have:

```
(\
"DSC009.jpg"\
"wallpaper.png"\
"image732.bmp"\
"animated.gif"\
)
```

I just need to switch that last `\` for a `)` and it should be good!

**//END OF UPDATE**

**About:**

I need to search all sub-folders for all files with specified extension(s) (.png, .jpg, gif, .bmp). Then ideally, output the full list of all results into a single variable **exactly as shown** in the example below. Results are case sensitive and must be wrapped in "double quotes" and separated by an escape character \ as shown. This is to be run from a bash script and NOT a shell prompt.

```
imagefiles=$(\
    "DSC009.jpg"\
    "wallpaper.png"\
    "image732.bmp"\
    "animated.gif")
```

I have searched here and elsewhere for the answers and tested code I found that I thought may work but all attempts failed, any help is appreciated.

So the code should look something like this:

var="$(insert code here)"

I have tried numerous solutions and variations, with no luck, even just getting some of the results I'm looking for. As someone suggested, here is one such attempt that failed. Again, these are just a few of the variations. I have tried unquoted, quoted, single quoted etc ($path contains no spaces).

```
imagefiles="find $path -type f -name \".\(png|jpg\|gif\|bmp\)\" -printf '%f\n'"

imagefiles=$("find $path -type f -name \".\(png|jpg\|gif\|bmp\)\""

imagefiles="$(find '$path' -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \))"

imagefiles="$(find $path -type f *.png)"
```

Again, none of the above work in even the simplest of ways, other then returning a single result at best.

**EDIT:**
For further clarification here is a another simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

#ROOT PATH OF FOLDERS CONTAINING IMAGES
path="/media/backup/photos/"

#FIND ALL IMAGE TYPES
imagefiles="$(find $path -type f '.\(png|jpg\|gif\|bmp\)\')"

#REMOVE IMAGE PATHS
list=`basename "$imagefiles"`

#CHECK TO VERIFY/DEBUG OUTPUT
echo "$list" > /media/found.txt
#FOUND.TXT SHOULD LOOK LIKE:
#DSC009.jpg
#wallpaper.png
#image732.bmp
#animated.gif

#CREATE NEW VARIABLE BUT SOMEHOW OUTPUT LIKE EXAMPLE BELOW
images="$(cat found.txt)"
#EXAMPLE:
#(\
#"DSC009.jpg"\
#"wallpaper.png"\
#"image732.bmp"\
#"animated.gif")
```

Hopefully this clears things up a little better.

Comment: Just put your `find` command in place of `insert code here`

Comment: Show what you tried that didn't work, and we'll help you fix it. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Would this happen to be a [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for something like "How do I assign `find` results to a shell array?" or "How do I invoke a command with `find` results as arguments?"

Comment: The given assignment will try to execute `DSC009.jpg` as a command (passing it the arguments "wallpaper.png", "image732.bmp", and "animated.gif"); it'll then assign the output of that (probably nothing because the that's not actually a command) to the variable `imagefiles`. I'm pretty sure this is not what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Barmar find on it's own doesn't work as I have tried that and will update the post to reflect that as you suggested.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Sorry for the confusion, those are not the same variables. IE: var=$imagefiles I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm still confused about exactly what you're trying to do. Are you trying to create a string which, if executed as part of a shell script, would define an array containing the filenames? That is, do you want the string's value to literally start with "`imagefiles=`" If so, you should almost certainly change your broader approach (see @thatotherguy's comment). Trying to store shell syntax (e.g. an assignment command) as strings tends not to work very well; see [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: No, I do not want the strings value to start with "`imagefiles=`".
As shown in the updated example, the variable should return with **ONLY** the following.

    "`(\
    "DSC009.jpg"\
    "wallpaper.png"\
     "image732.bmp"\
    "animated.gif")`"

Where the filenames can be anything as can the extensions.

Comment: That looks like just one filename, since you've escaped the spaces. What's your END goal here? What do you want to do with the list of files? Put them in an array? Provide them as input to some other program? Run a command on each of them?

Comment: @ghoti The end goal was to have a list of the filenames in the specified format fed into a variable. You could consider the list itself an array of sorts I suppose. It will be provided to an external program which will list the images and display them when clicked. I can't say more then that.

Comment: Well then, use an actual array and pathname expansion. `files=($path/*.{png,jpg,gif,bmp})`

Comment: @ghoti That will not work for me, but thanks for the suggestion, also in case you hadn't seen this has been solved, so no further action is needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Special thanks to @Richard Jessop & @that other guy for their posts which helped point me in the right direction. As well as any one else that took the time and effort to comment.*

I know that parsing from `ls` is taboo as [mentioned here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), however in my case it works as intended and was easy to setup.

If you know of a better way to achieve the same results, then please by all means feel free to share it for others. Keep in mind, in my case `-printf` is not available.

Here is the working solution I was after!

```
#!/bin/bash

imagePath="/media/photos/"

#Remove the previous results before beginning
rm -f /media/images.txt

#List all images found with matching extensions and output only the filenames to images.txt file.
for images in $(ls -a -R $imagePath | egrep '\.JPG$|\.jpg$|\.png$|\.PNG$')
do
   #Output filenames like so "IMAGENAME.EXT"\
   echo -e "   \"$images\"\\" >> /media/images.txt
done

#'1i (\\' Starts the file with (\ and '$s,\\$,),' substitutes the final \ with a ).  
sed -i -e '1i (\\' -e '$s,\\$,),' /media/images.txt

#Creates a Variable from the output in the images.txt file.
myVar=$(cat /media/images.txt)

#See, it works!
echo "$myVar"
```

Comment: So..  I would replace your for loop with this to create an array of filenames: `shopt -s nocaseglob; images=($imagePath/*.{jpg.png})`, then split the array into your variable with `printf -v myVar '%s\n' "${images[@]}"`. Then add your wrapper: `printf -v myVar '(\\\n%s)' "$myVar"`. No loop, no temp file. If you want to strip off path info, `images=(${images[@]##*/})` before you create `$myVar`. Note that we could not possibly have come up with this based on your question.

Comment: @ghoti A few issues with this. **1:** Your first snippet of code had two errors. Well one error and one unnecessary character. It should be as follows: `shopt -s nocaseglob; images=($imagePath*.{jpg,png})` **2:** The code fails to search for images recursively, and unfortunately `globstar` is unavailable. In my case, knowing my folder structure, a simple fix would be `shopt -s nocaseglob dotglob; images=($imagePath*/*.{jpg,png})`. Here I have added `dotglob` to handle any hidden files or folders that may start with a dot `.`, as well as used an `*` to tell it to look in all sub folders.

Comment: It's not perfect as it of course will only search a min/maxDepth of 1.

Comment: @ghoti I didn't even notice it the other day, but the wrapper you posted is also incomplete. As the code above demonstrates the resulting effects of this portion are missing `echo -e "   \"$images\"\\" >> /media/images.txt`

Comment: Well, I wrote a comment, not an answer. And I wrote it freehand, so typos happen. It's up to you to figure out how you want to use any advice you get, or if you even want to bother levelling up your bash skills. Note that double slashes are functionally equivalent to single slashes, and protect you in case your `$imagePath` doesn't end in a slash. And if your goal is to put array contents into a file, something like `printf ' "%s"' "${images[@]}" > images.txt` would seem to be an option, though it would of course fail on filenames containing quotes.

Comment: @ghoti Well in my case looking at my code above you can see `imagePath` does in fact end with an `/`, so the double slash prevented the code from working. But as you said, this was a comment not an answer. Also to clear up any confusion (If I'm not misunderstanding) there are no quotes in the filenames. They're added. So simply using `printf -v myVar '\"%s\"\n' "${images[@]}"` does that task just fine. The only part of your suggested code I've yet to get working as in my own, is changing the final  \ to a ).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an partial solution:

```
for file in $(find . -mindepth 1 | egrep '\.(png|txt)$')
do
    echo -e "   \"$file\"\\"
done
```

The mindepth option skips the current directory.  I tried to move the egrep inside the find which has that option, but I couldn't get it to work.

This will get you your multiple, indented lines terminated with \.
Hopefully, you or someone else can fill in the rest of details.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of -mindepth and had used it previously as well in my tests. Unfortunately, this solution didn't produce any output for me. I will let you know if I have any success getting it to work.

Comment: By replacing "find ." with "find $path", I was able to get output, but it only produced a single file as my other results have, and didn't exclude the path from the output, the later of course is not a problem.

Comment: So I have been able to get this working by using `ls -a -R $path | egrep '\.(png|txt)$')` But the echo is issuing a final \ on the last line where it should not so I'll have to see about removing it. Then just need to enclose it in `()` and it should work. Naturally I'm aware it is taboo to use ls in this way, but unless someone can present something that works, I see no other alternative.

Comment: Solved it! Will update the post once I clean up and confirm it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find -printf` to output each result the way you want it. The header and modification of the last element can easily be done with `sed`:

```
myvar="$(
  find "${path?}" \( -name '*.png' -o -name '*.jpg' \)  -printf '"%f"\\\n' |
    sed -e '1i(\\' -e '$s,\\$,),'
)"
```

This uses `1i` to specify an insertion on line 1, and `$s` to do a substitution on the last line, specifically a trailing `\` with a `)`

If you need it more POSIX compliant, you can do:

```
myvar="$(
  printf '%s\n' '(\'
  find "${path?}" -name '*.png' -o -name '*.jpg' |
    sed -e 's,\(.*/\)*\(.*\),"\2"\\,' -e '$s,\\$,),'
)"
```

Comment: I have tried find -printf with no luck. And I'm actually using sed 1i in my latest code which works, albeit with a small issue left over as I have described in the updated original topic above. I will test this though and let you know.

Comment: Turns out that `-printf` isn't available. It should be...but I get this error: `find: unrecognized: -printf`

Comment: I actually also didn't want a trailing `\)`. Just a `)` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to solve it. It's not perfect but it works perfect, but I will update the post once I clean up and confirm it works.

Comment: Can you check that you're actually on Linux and not on macOS?

Comment: Linux. Not sure where you got macOS from.

Comment: Why are you saying that `-printf` should be available? It's available in GNU find but not e.g. BusyBox find. Does it show up in the man page? If so, you probably have both userlands installed. If not, you'd want e.g. a BusyBox/Linux solution rather than a more typical GNU/Linux solution

Comment: `printf` is available. find `-printf` is not. 

Regardless I have found a working solution. Thank you for your help. I will update the post soon to reflect my findings.

Feel free to post a solution for BusyBox/Linux if you think it will help others.